# If real $f$ is such that $\exists\delta>0:\ \forall\varepsilon>0,\vert x-y\vert<\delta\implies\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert<\varepsilon.$ Then $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity, alternative-proof, epsilon-delta

> *Proposition*: Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\ $ has the property:
>
> $$ \exists\ \delta > 0:\quad \forall\ \varepsilon > 0,\ \vert x-y\vert
>  < \delta \implies \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert < \varepsilon.\quad (1) $$
>
> Then $f$ is a constant function.

*Proof*:

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\ $ has property $\ (1),\ $ and $f$ is non-constant, that is, $\ \exists\ x_1 \neq x_2\ $ with
$\ f(x_1)\neq f(x_2).$

Let $\ \alpha = \left\lceil \frac{ \vert x_2 - x_1 \vert }{ \delta } \right \rceil + 1,\ $ so that $\ \beta: = \frac{ \vert x_2 - x_1\vert }{ \alpha } < \delta,\ $ and set $\ \varepsilon = \frac{ \vert f(x_2) - f(x_1) \vert }{ \alpha }.$

Since $\ \vert x_1 + k\beta - (x_1 + (k-1)\beta ) \vert = \beta < \delta\quad \forall\ k\in\{1,2,\ldots,\alpha\},$

$(1)\implies \vert f(x_1 + k\beta) - f(x_1 + (k-1)\beta) \vert < \varepsilon\quad \forall\ k\in\{1,2,\ldots,\alpha\}.\ $ It follows that:

$$ \vert f(x_2 - f(x_1) \vert = \left \lvert \sum_{k=1}^{k=\alpha} f(x_1 + k\beta) - f(x_1 + (k-1)\beta) \right \rvert$$ $$ \leq \sum_{k=1}^{k=\alpha} \left \lvert f(x_1 + k\beta) - f(x_1 + (k-1)\beta) \right \rvert $$

$$ < \alpha \varepsilon = \vert f(x_2) - f(x_1) \vert\ \Rightarrow \Leftarrow.$$

I would like to know: (a) if my proof is correct, as I felt confused when writing it, and (b) if there are any good alternative approaches, as my proof seems like overkill to me.

I am aware that, since $\ f\ $ has property $(1),\ f\ $ is uniformly continuous and therefore continuous also. Therefore the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) applies to every interval $\ I\subset\mathbb{R}.\ $ However, I didn't mention these facts in my proof because I didn't use them. Maybe an alternative approach would make good use of them?

Comment: Your proof seems correct. Showing first that $f$ is constant on any interval $(a,b)$ where $a-b\lt 2\delta$ and then using the connectedness of $\mathbb{R}$ would be an alternative approach.

Comment: Note that (1) is equivalent to $\exists \delta > 0: |x-y| < \delta \implies f(x) = f(y)$.

Comment: @Acrobatic that sounds interesting, I didn't think of that and I don't know what that proof would look like, so please feel free to post it as an answer!

Comment: If you show that $f$ is constant on any interval $(a,b)$, then this is the same as showing that it is locally constant. A locally constant function on a connected set must be constant. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, the result follows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is ok.

What is interesting here is that the condition:

$$\exists\delta>0:\ \forall\varepsilon>0:\ \vert x-y\vert<\delta\implies\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert<\varepsilon$$

implies that, for that chosen $\delta$, whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ it must be $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ *for every $\varepsilon>0$*. So, $|f(x)-f(y)|$ is smaller than any positive number $\varepsilon$, so it must be zero, i.e.:

$$\exists\delta>0:\ \vert x-y\vert<\delta\implies f(x)=f(y)$$

So, the function is constant on any interval of size $\delta$, and you can see that this easily implies that it is constant on the entire $\mathbb R$.

---

**Update** The "easily implies" bit above may still require a proof. Let $x<y$: subdivide the segment $[x,y]$ by points $x_0=x<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_{n-1}<x_n=y$ such that all $x_{k+1}-x_k<\delta$. Then, the previous consideration implies that $f(x)=f(x_0)=f(x_1)=f(x_2)=\cdots=f(x_{n-1})=f(x_n)=f(y)$.

Comment: "and you can see that this easily implies that it is constant on the entire R." You would still need to prove this. One way is similar to my method in the question (proof by contradiction). Another way is by induction on overlapping intervals to the left and also to the right of a fixed interval. My point is that, "It's obvious" still isn't a proof...

Comment: Whether I would still need to prove it depends on the context. You have to admit that the proof is fairly elementary, that is why I initially omitted it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very basic proof. Let $x,y \in \mathbb R$ be such that $|x-y| < \delta$. Then forall $\epsilon > 0$ you have
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon
$$
which means $f(x)=f(y)$. It is then easy to check that $f$ is constant on any open interval of length $\delta$. Cover $\mathbb R$ with open intervals of length $\leq \delta$ that are overlapping, say $I_n = (n\delta/2 , (n/2+1)\delta),\quad n\in \mathbb Z$. Then you know that forall $n \in \mathbb Z$, $f$ is constant on $I_n$, and you are left to check that each of these constant are in fact equal. This can be done by induction, let me show that forall $n \in \mathbb N$, $f$ is constant to $f(\delta/2)$ on $I_n$.

- On $I_0 = (0 , \delta)$, $f$ is constant to $f(\delta/2)$.
- If on $I_n,\quad n \in \mathbb N$, $f$ is constant to $f(\delta/2)$ we have that on $I_{n+1}$ the function $f$ is constant. But now use the overlapping property: observe that the set
  $$
  I_n \cap I_{n+1} = (n\delta/2 , (n/2+1)\delta) \cap ((n+1)\delta/2 , ((n+1)/2+1)\delta) = ((n+1)\delta/2 , (n/2+1)\delta)
  $$
  contains one point, say $x_n = (n/2 + 3/4)\delta$, and discover
  $$
  f(x) = f(x_n) = f(\delta/2)
  $$
  forall $x \in I_{n+1}$.

The same proof works for $n \in \mathbb Z_-$.